# SecurityError: Error #2028: Local-with-filesystem SWF file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-maps, api-key

I don't know how to tell the flash to let the swf file get connected.
I used the crossdomain.xml as well but nothing have changed.
here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


        <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">


        <cross-domain-policy>


            <allow-access-from domain="*" />


        </cross-domain-policy>
```

and here is the error on the swf file when i run it from my own computer(this one solved):

```
SecurityError: Error #2028: Local-with-filesystem SWF file file:///*/index.swf cannot access Internet URL http://maps.googleapis.com/*.
    at flash.display::Loader/_load()
    at flash.display::Loader/load()
    at BootstrapConfiguration/loadAddingAcceptLanguageHeaderIfAir()
    at com.google.maps::ClientBootstrap/loadUrl()
    at com.google.maps::ClientBootstrap/internalLoadBootstrap()
    at com.google.maps::ClientBootstrap/executeNextFrameCalls()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

and here is error when i run the swf file from the website:

```
Initialization failed: please check the API key,
swf location, version and network availability.
```

what should i do now!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set "-use-network=true" in compiler's options or appropriate option in your IDE. It may help.

Comment: the question is what is that appropriate option in my IDE (flash cs6) ?

Comment: i solve a bit of my problem. now with the cfg file in my flash player security folder the swf file works fine on my computer and the error went away. but i still have the same problem on the website.

Comment: In CS6 this option can be changed at "File->Publish settings->Advanced->Local playback security

Comment: OK it has 2 options: 1.Access Network Only 2.Access Local Files Only. and i used both options but i still have the problem on my website.

Comment: i also write this code at the first frame: Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.LOCAL_WITH_NETWORK;
Security.loadPolicyFile("daniel-3dpanel.ir/crossdomain.xml");